# How to interpret 主题先行？

Tags: meaning

This is 张东阁 speaking. I think to understand this, I need to understand the mentality of China in the 1970s, but still, "主题先行" puzzles me. "Themes go first"?? What themes?

我是在上世纪70年代开始剪纸创作。
I started doing paper-cutting last century in the 70s.
当时收到“主题先行”的创作思潮影响，
At that time I was influenced by the "big themes come first" creative tide of thought,
一味追求服务于时代，
I only wanted to serve our country at that time,
抓大题材，
take up the important themes,
抓时代气息，
grasp the Zeitgeist,
因此，
therefore,
在表现手法上大都抛弃了传统剪纸的影响。
in my expressive technique I mostly abandoned the influence of traditional paper-cutting.

Comment: 主题先行 here should be a technical term in 剪纸创作. This might not be a language question, but a technical one.

Comment: just some quick notes: #1 http://www.scidict.org/index.aspx?word=%E4%B8%BB%E9%A2%98%E5%85%88%E8%A1%8C  [电子信息,商业经济,生活,人文] 主题先行 theme first  收藏  跳转到该词 #2 https://books.google.com/books?id=PnE3DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT99&lpg=PT99&dq=%22%E4%B8%BB%E9%A2%98%E5%85%88%E8%A1%8C%22+Subject+First&source=bl&ots=-aQUypdwBq&sig=mecnWJx7bo3__jketKCBmSBjedc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjU-ZGotcrYAhUGy2MKHaHtDmUQ6AEIQDAD 影響比較:格里爾遜式與主題先行[Comparison and Influence: Grierson Mode and Subject First] #3 https://www.aaa.org.hk/en/collection/search/library/idea-performance-no-5-5 Idea Performance (No. 5), 主題先行 (總第5期）#4 subject choosing

Comment: #5 https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=16&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiLju2Et8rYAhVR92MKHYR7Cnc4ChAWCEswBQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.xjishu.com%2Fen%2F063%2Fy389147.html&usg=AOvVaw0AE19NSUelS1c39sp1VO_x 10.Hu Feng Subject View and Subject Advance Thought Probe;胡风的主题观及其主题先行思想试探

Comment: 当时**受**到“主题先行”的创作思潮影响

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[主题先行](http://www.baike.com/wiki/%E4%B8%BB%E9%A2%98%E5%85%88%E8%A1%8C), as you said, it literally means "Themes go first".

But, "70年代" is the Cultural Revolution period, I suppose it refers to the situation that before artistic creation, the central theme has been decided by political factors; people has to do the creation accord with that.

> “主题先行”指十年动乱期间，根据政治需要，先确定所谓的“主题”，然后再根据“主题”的要求填进“人物”和“情节”，使“主题”得以表现的一种文学创作方法。

Comment: different time period: https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%BB%E9%A2%98%E5%85%88%E8%A1%8C  “主题先行”指民国白色恐怖动乱期间...

Comment: @user6065 It's not the case for OP, who said it's "70年代".

Comment: @user6065 Do not trust baike.baidu. Many like this one are maliciously tampered.